# Generate url in MVC Api Controller

Tags: api, model-view-controller, routes

I am using both Api and routing controller in my web app. My api controller is used to retrieve the link to the page that shows the information about an item. The page is rendered using the traditional mvc controller.

In the api controller, how do I generate the link to the page? Of course I could generate the link by hardcoding the routing path but I'd like to take advantage of the routing capability in mvc.

People have suggested to use UrlHelper.Action, but looks like it cannot be used in Api controller, or am I missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Url.Link, that will work fine. Check out [Using the asp.net web api urlhelper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roncain/archive/2012/07/17/using-the-asp-net-web-api-urlhelper.aspx) for more info